# No way to pass new argument to `init` for `NSView`

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In the following code, I'm trying to pass an additional argument to `VidePlayerView`. Right now, I'm creating an instance of `VideoPlayerView` and I'm passing no arguments to it. However, this ends up calling the `init` methods with an `NSRect` arguments (which I don't really know where that comes from).

I want to pass an additional argument to `VideoPlayerView`, but I have no idea how to do this since it seems that I don't have access to the `frame` argument.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

// Note: I couldn't find a way to pass this through the `init` method
var playerLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

final class VideoPlayerView: NSView {

    // MARK: - Initializers
    override public init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        // Do something with playerLayer
    }
}

public struct VideoPlayerViewView: NSViewRepresentable {

    init(layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?) {
        if let layer = layer {
            playerLayer = layer
        } else {
            print("No Layer Set")
        }

    }

    public func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<VideoPlayerViewView>) -> NSView {
        return VideoPlayerView()
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm solving this problem by ignoring the `frame` argument, but not sure if that is important.

```
final class VideoPlayerView: NSView {

    private var playerLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    private let rootLayer = CALayer()

    // MARK: - Initializers
    override public init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    public init(layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        self.playerLayer = layer
        super.init(frame: NSRect())
        commonInit()
    }
...
 public func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<VideoPlayerViewView>) -> NSView {
        return VideoPlayerView(layer: self.playerLayer)
    }
```

Comment: Can you not use the bounds of the relevant layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
final class VideoPlayerView: NSView {
    private var playerLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    // MARK: - Initializers
    override public init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    public convenience init(frame frameRect: NSRect = .zero, layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?) {
        self.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.playerLayer = layer
    }

    required public init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        // Do something with playerLayer
    }
}

public struct VideoPlayerViewView: NSViewRepresentable {

    init(layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?) {
        if let layer = layer {
            playerLayer = layer
        } else {
            print("No Layer Set")
        }

    }

    public func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<VideoPlayerViewView>) -> NSView {
        return VideoPlayerView(layer: playerLayer)
    }

    public func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```